# SQL about duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mysql-workbench, database-normalization

I have a general question about data normalisation (my first steps into SQL). I was given a CSV file which I have uploaded to MySQL workbench and was asked to do data normalisation (use normal forms). I have found some obvious duplicates, but I am unsure about one thing. There is data about companies and their addresses, but, for example in "Country" field, UNITED STATES is repeated  few thousand times and I was unsure does that count as duplicate data? Should I make separate table, for instance, "Countries" and give them unique ID, let's say 1 for US and then update data in the original table where there is US replace it with 1?

Comment: Please describe the scope for *duplicate record* in your case: a single column, all of the columns? And also would be perfect if you could share a sample data and the sql you've tried so far.

Comment: No it does not count as duplicate data in the companies table (the same would apply to city, zipcode etc) but you do need a countries (and city and zipcode) table for verification (to ensure referential integrity) and enrichment purposes (ie you may chose to store a short code USA in companies but print a long name United States Of America. Think 3 character airport codes.

Comment: Would you please paste a small sample of your data? This would greatly help.

Comment: Yes, Countries table is required here. If you want to search on Country name then INT works faster that VARCHAR or STRING value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to eliminate duplicates, then `'UNITED STATES'` is, indeed, a duplicate.

So, a `countries` reference table would be called for, if your goal is normalization.

Note that in this case, normalization will probably *reduce* the size of the data.  Your key for the `countries` table will probably be an integer (4 bytes) -- although it could also be ISO 2-character or 3-character country codes.  Repeating the primary key in the original table should reduce the overall size of the data in the database.

Comment: Would it be the same case with State and City?

Comment: @Newbie187 . . . If you are referring to "state" as an intermediate between "country" and "city", then yes.  Full normalization would require three tables.  However, I would probably have one city table with repeated columns for state and country (denormalizing the geography dimension).